# MCP23017 - what does the postfix mean? -E -E/SO -E/SS -E/SP

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm working on a DIY-project with the port expander MCP23017. Right now, I already visited several online shops to compare the prices of that module. Some of these shops call their products like "MCP23017 -E", "MCP23017-E/SO", "MCP23017 -E/SS", "MCP23017-E/SP".

Are there any significant differences among these products? Or is it just some kind of individual naming?

Thank you for your support

Comment: Have you read data sheet? Does it clarify? (I could speculate that one of them means bus type I²C vs. SPI) Often it simply means type of package (TSOP, DIP, etc).